# Using an XPath on current-group()

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I need to select a subset of the nodes of a of the `current-group()` in an `xsl:for-each-group` loop.  When I use an XPath of the form `current-group()/foo`, nothing is matched.  If, however, I bind the current group to a variable like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="foo"><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></xsl:variable>
```

and then use an XPath of the form `$foo/foo`, I get the expected matches.  I suspect that the issue is somehow related with the type of `current-group()` and how the `$foo` variable has a different type, but I can't seem to figure it out by myself.  Any clues how I can avoid introducing a variable to make the type conversion?  Or is it something different?

Comment: What are you selecting in your for-each-group? Is `foo` a child element of whatever is selected? An [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help us understand the question.

Answer (score 3):

if you do something like:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="foo" group-by="type">
   <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[self::foo]"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Then `current-group()` returns sequence of elements

But

```
<xsl:variable name="foo">
   <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

returns a document node which contains sequence of foo, and then you need to use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="current-group()/foo"/>
```